# How can I increase the severety warning of required parameter in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

In the past when I missed a required parameter of a method, PhpStorm underlined the method in red color. However, I may have changed something and now it doesn't.
[image]

It is displayed with error severity on the Problems tab, but not in the editor.
Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Basically, this inspection type underlines not the whole function/method but only arguments inside of the braces. Also, please check the "PHP > Type compatibility > Parameter Type" and please try altering its highlight settings as this is the inspection that fires up here.

Comment: Thanks for replying, @duck_in_hat. I didn't find this path. Where exactly is it?

Comment: @RicardoMartins *"I didn't find this path. Where exactly is it?"* First navigate to **Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Inspections** as you have on your last screenshot, then `PHP | Type compatibility | Parameter type`. It's there in 2022.1.4

Comment: @RicardoMartins You can go to the corresponding inspection right from the editor. Just place the caret on the issue, then invoke the Intentions/Quick Fix menu (`Alt+Enter` here on Windows; or using the mouse on the Light Bulb icon), locate the right entry and expand the submenu for it (just use `Arrow Right` on a keyboard -- it's hard to click using a mouse as it has quite small hitbox). Then just choose the desired entry there.

Comment: @RicardoMartins NOTE: the "Parameters number mismatch declaration" is used when your function has 2 parameters and you provide 3+. This inspection will not work for your case as it has less parameters that expected.

Comment: That's it @LazyOne!!! The **Parameter type** option! Thank you very much. Feel free to add that as an answer and I mark it as the correct answer.